# How can i fix SIGSEGV on thread : -1327498896 error in c++?

Tags: c++

> SIGSEGV on thread : -1327498896

Above error is on mobile based c++ offline compiler. Its a program to add complex numbers.

I have gone through similar answers but none works for me.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex 
{
    private:
    int a,b;

    public:
    void setData(int x, int y)
    {
        a=x; b=y;
    }
    void showData()
    {
        cout<<"\na = "<<a<<", "<<"b = "<<b;
    }
   Complex add(Complex c)
    {
         Complex temp;
         temp.a = a+c.a;
         temp.b = b+c.b;
         return(temp);         
    }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1;
    Complex c2;
    Complex c3;

    c1.setData(3, 4);
    c2.setData(5, 6);
    c3=c1.add(c2);
    c3.showData();
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Aside from a few functions missing a `return` statement (change their return type to `void`), your code is fine.

Comment: I suspect a problem in your compiler or the rest of the environment. (What is a "mobile based offline compiler"?)

Comment: @Botje   I tried with using void as return type still. Throws the same error.

Comment: @molbdnilo Its an app on android for c, c++ offline coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its not an issue with most compilers, some do not allow *accessing* of **private** members in a class for a case like yours, which is the reason why `SIGSEV` gets triggered for illegal memory access (or memory access violation).

Changing the scope of your variables to public will solve the issue:

```cpp
public:
int a,b;
```

Comment: Sir, i changed int to void. But still same error throws.

Comment: @Abhi Cannot reproduce your error, what application are you using? Better to use any online compiler out there.

Comment: sir, Can u suggest me what changes i should brought in question so that my negetive vote will eliminate?

Comment: @Abhi I didn't downvote. (only the one who did can remove that) Your question's error lacks reproducibility - which seems to be the cause of the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this. By slight change in the name of add()

Old

```
Complex add(Complex c)
    {
         Complex temp;
         temp.a = a+c.a;
         temp.b = b+c.b;
         return(temp);         
    }
```

New

```
Complex operator +(Complex c)
    {
         Complex temp;
         temp.a = a+c.a;
         temp.b = b+c.b;
         return(temp);         
    }
```

Above change fix my error.

Comment: This might be just a use and throw method. But it worked. I dont know how. I welcome explaination for knowledge purpose. Thanks all for

Comment: Its called operator overloading. But this doesn't explain why your previous code resulted in SIGSEV (?)

Comment: Yes sir, i am also looking for an explanation on above error? If you find it. Please post it here.

Comment: There might be some issue with compilor.

Comment: whats the compiler?

Comment: Try your previous code (one posted in question) on that compiler with `int a,b;` under `public:` scope. (It does not matter in most compilers, but accessing private members might give an access violation in some)

Comment: @Anirban166 compilor is clang 6.0.0